# python pandas columns contain dict

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I got some trouble.

```
import pandas
df=pandas.DataFrame([[{'a':1,'b':2},3,3],[{'a':2,'b':4},6,5]],columns=['c1','c2','c3'])
print df

                   c1  c2  c3
0  {u'a': 1, u'b': 2}   3   3
1  {u'a': 2, u'b': 4}   6   5
```

I want to get the result like this:

```
   b  c3
0  2   3
1  4   5
```

I try use the df.loc[:,['c1','c3']]. but I don't know next step how I should do.
thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with `df1` created with `DataFrame` constructor - first convert column `c1` to `numpy array` by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html) and then to `list`:

```
df=pd.DataFrame([[{'a':1,'b':2},2,3],[{'a':2,'b':4},4,5]],columns=['c1','c2','c3'])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.c1.values.tolist())
print (df1)
   a  b
0  1  2
1  2  4

print (pd.concat([df1[['b']], df[['c3']]], axis=1))
   b  c3
0  2   3
1  4   5
```